# New Samsung XP941 SSD showing values for "Used Reserved Block Count". Is this bad?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a brand new Samsung 512GB XP941 SSD. Installed Windows and had it all up and running for about a week now. 
However... when I ran Crystal Disk Info it's only showing a Health Status of 92% and already has values for "Used Reserved Block Count" which from what I've read, means it encountered W/R errors on some blocks so it remapped them to blocks in the reserve.

Specifically it says:
Used Reserved Block Count (Total): 2E7
Un-used Reserved Block Count (Total): 2619

Does this mean I got a bad drive and should RMA it?

Comment: They're OEM drives. Hence, it's entirely possible that Samsung considers it the OEM system builder's responsibility to handle defective blocks present at manufacturing time.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most SSDs that ship with these values set to zero, it seems that it is at least sorta normal for the XP941. The reason I think this, is that my XP941 is also showing 92% and I found a review at [TechnologyX](http://www.technologyx.com/featured/samsung-xp941-ssd-review/2/) and they show the Crystal DiskInfo results and it is showing 90% on a drive that has only been powered on 3 times.  So at least 3 drives have roughly the same situation, not enough for statistics of course, but I haven't found anything else.

If I'm wrong, somebody please let me know and I'll try to get mine replaced too!

NECROEDIT: After ~3 years my XP941 is still working fine and still showing 92% wear, so clearly it has not been a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I thought, that my new (4 times powered on) mSATA EVO 850 500GB shows the same data:

- Used Reserved Block Count (total) 10
- Program Fail Count  (total) 10
- Erase Fail Count (totl) 10
- Runtime Bad Count (total) 10,

But then I saw, that I was mistaken, because I looked at the threshold column, so all is OK with my EVO 850 SSD.

May be it'll help somebody.